# Getting a true or false reply to a Regex match?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to match an entire string against a regex formula. This is for validating if a phone number field is likely correct (just based on allowed characters, anyone can make up an number). I've played with Regex before but never truly understood the nuances that make it powerful.

Below I have my dummy phone number and I have the regex I'm using. As you can see I'm simply comparing the length of the match vs the length of the string and if they match the number must be valid.

Is there a way to get a simple true/false reply from a Regex check on an entire string?

```
var num = '+1 (888) 456-7896';
var regex = /[0-9+ ()-]*$/;
var found = num.match(regex);

console.log(found[0].length);
console.log(num.length);
```

Comment: Yes see `RegExp.prototype.test` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: `/regex_pattern/.test(string_here)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
var found = regex.test(num);
```